# Setting the generic parameter from an object's variable

Tags: c#, generics, generic-programming

Say I have a number of different classes that implement this interface:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    Type ResponseType { get; }
}
```

Where the idea is that each Request-class specifies the Type of the reponse it would receive.

And I have a class for serializing/deserializing, where the deserialize-method signature is so:

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : IRequest
{ ... }
```

How can I call Deserialize, and use the `ResponseType` variable as the generic parameter?

```
var request = new SomeRequest() // object which implements IRequest
byte[] receivedData = myNetworkService.SendRequest(request.Serialize());
var response = MyBinarySerializer.Deserialize<request.ResponseType>(receivedData);
```

Or is there another way to go about this? The class I am using for serializing/deserializing is 3rd party, so I cannot change it. Its `Deserialize<T>()` needs to be called with the generic parameter `T`

Comment: What is `MyBinarySerializer`?

Comment: @haim770 This one unfortunately does not.

Comment: https://github.com/jefffhaynes/BinarySerializer/blob/master/BinarySerializer/BinarySerializer.cs#L153

Answer (score 1):

You can add another overload of `Deserialize` which accepts a `Type` argument. Then you can delegate the generic call to that as well.

```
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : IRequest
{ 
    return Deserialize(typeof(T), byte[] data) as T;
}

public static object Deserialize(Type, byte[] data)
{ 
   ...
}
```

Comment: the OP  did not provide supplementation details but I presume he controls it so it shouldn't be a problem to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

The generic parameter is a design time type, where the property is a runtime type. You can't use a runtime type as a design time type, but there should be an overload of Deserialize that takes a type:

```
object deserialisedObject =  Deserialise(Type t, Object o);
if(deserialisedObject is MyType)
{
    var property = ((MyType)deserialisedObject).MyProperty;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately the lib I am using for serializing does not have a non-generic Deserialize method, so the only way to call it is with the generic type parameter.